# socket.io not working when i deploy my app to heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, socket.io

my app was working fine locally with socket.io but when i deploy it to heroku it didn't work , i know the error because the socket setup on the client work on localhost:5000 but i don't know how to solve it

this is the server file

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

// create a server for socket io
const http = require('http');
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const server = http.createServer(app);
module.exports = io = socketio(server);

// my middle ware
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Init Middelware
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));

// my router
const postRoute = require('./nodeapi/routers/post');
const authRouter = require('./nodeapi/routers/auth');
const usersRouter = require('./nodeapi/routers/users');
const friendRouter = require('./nodeapi/routers/friend');
const chatRouter = require('./nodeapi/routers/chats');
const mongoDB = require('./nodeapi/mongodb-database/db');
const port = process.env.PORT;

// Connect monogo database
mongoDB();

// Middel ware
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Get the routes
app.use('/', postRoute);
app.use('/', authRouter);
app.use('/', usersRouter);
app.use('/', friendRouter);
app.use('/', chatRouter);
app.use('/file/', express.static('uploads/'));

// connect to socket io
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('Client connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', () => console.log('Client disconnected'));
});
//Serve static assets in productio
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Set static folder
  app.use(express.static('./client/build'));
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
}
// listen to the port
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`this is port ${port}`);
});
```

this is the setup of socket in client side

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

let socket = io('http://localhost:5000');

export default socket;
```

Comment: So on the client side, you just specify the URL to your hosted app, without the port.
`const client = io('https://some-app.herokuapp.com')`. I had a similar problem and this worked for me.

Comment: You can also just invoke the io method itself with no parameter and it should work.  `const client = io()`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of letting your sockets to connect with a static URL, you should try using

```
let socket = io(window.location.origin)
```

So that your client-side connects with the server it is deployed on or if your server is deployed somewhere else you can write

```
let socket = io('url_of_deployed_server')
```

so that your client-side is able to communicate with the server using sockets.